# macros in Z3 that define variables and constants

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, z3

I would like to have macros in Z3 that can define variables and constants. I can't figure out how to do this with the language, so I am using cpp (the c preprocessor) to do it.

For example, I have:

```
#define CONST(NAME,VALUE) (declare-const NAME Int) (assert (= NAME VALUE))
```

And then I can define constants, like:

```
CONST(MIN_AGE, 10)
CONST(MAX_AGE, 140)
```

Is there a way to do this within the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to write these in SMTLib would be:

```
(define-fun MIN_AGE () Int  10)
(define-fun MAX_AGE () Int 140)
```

Note the use of the `define-fun` construct instead of `declare-const`, which declares and associates a name with a constant value.

See http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/ for detailed information on the language. In particular, this [document](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf) standardizes the syntax and semantics across solvers. The `define-fun` command is described on page 62.

Note that SMTLib is not really intended to be "hand" written. It is more suitable for machine generation. Most SMT users will use a higher-level API which will use SMT-Lib under the hood (or a different mechanism) to communicate with the solver. There are choices in all major languages, including C/C++/Java/Python/Haskell/O'Caml and others, with varying levels of maturity and features they support. My recommendation would be to pick one of these languages and use their API instead, instead of directly coding in SMTLib.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a document where I would find this? I find the whole language to be somewhat impenetrable.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it.